# SQL Server MERGE statement with "DUAL" in using clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

With Oracle (or DB2, HSQLDB), I can express things like this:

```
MERGE INTO [target_table]
USING (SELECT 1 FROM dual)
ON [target_table.id = 5]
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...
```

This just checks if there is already a record with `id = 5` in `target_table`. If there is, then the record is update, if there isn't then it is inserted. This is roughly the same as MySQL's more concise

```
INSERT INTO [target_table] ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

How can I do that in SQL Server? According to the documentation, the `[table_source]` needs to be any of these:

```
<table_source> ::= 
{
  table_or_view_name [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ <tablesample_clause> ] 
        [ WITH ( table_hint [ [ , ]...n ] ) ] 
  | rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ] 
        [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ] 
  | user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
  | OPENXML <openxml_clause> 
  | derived_table [ AS ] table_alias [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ] 
  | <joined_table> 
  | <pivoted_table> 
  | <unpivoted_table>
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb510625.aspx

Obviously, SQL Server does not have a `DUAL` table, but neither is a `SELECT` statement allowed. What can I put as `[table_source]` ?

N.B: I found out that I can create a dummy view

```
CREATE VIEW dummy (one) AS SELECT 1;
```

and supply that as the `[table_source]`. But I would like to omit DDL statements just to be able to execute this `MERGE` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) -- look at the example "C. Using MERGE to perform UPDATE and INSERT operations on a target table by using a derived source table" which uses `VALUES` (aka [Table Value Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)):

```
MERGE INTO Target
USING (VALUES (1))
       AS Source (Number)
...
```

Happy coding.

Comment: I'm dumb. Of course, it says in the syntax definition: `derived_table [ AS ] table_alias [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]` I just didn't realise that aliasing is mandatory in this case! Thanks!

Comment: `merge into target_table t USING(SELECT 5 id) s ON (t.id = s.id) ...`